# How to simplify an elasticsearch BoolQuery with only a simple Filter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

The following code creates a string s containing the query string s below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Elasticsearch.Net;
using Nest;

public void MyTest()
{
    QueryBase query = new TermQuery
    {
        Field = Infer.Field<MyDocument>(f => f.Title),
        Value = "MyTitle"
    };
    var booleanQuery = new BoolQuery();
    var containers = new List<QueryContainer> { query };
    booleanQuery.Filter = containers;
    var request = new SearchRequest<MyDocument>("MyIndex")
    {
        Query = booleanQuery
    };
    var elasticClient = new ElasticClient();
    var s = elasticClient.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(request, SerializationFormatting.Indented);
}
```

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{
          "term": {
            "title": {
              "value": "MyTitle"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to simplify the request so that the "filter" ist not an array but directly contains the query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "title": {
            "value": "MyTitle"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can this be done by modifying my code? Keeping the object initializer syntax.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you want to do it ? because at the end both query will work in same way.

Comment: @SagarPatel There is no specific reason. Just want to know if this is possible since [all the examples here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-bool-query.html) show it without an array

Comment: ok... got it. it support both the way.. but even if you pass without array then also internally it will go with array only. so as per my suggestion you can keep with array.